# Count values from Java Object?

Tags: java

I have this Java object which is used to store item:

```
public class PaymentDetailsItem
{
    private String name;
    private String amount;
    private int quantity;
    private String currencyID;

    public PaymentDetailsItem(String name, String amount, int quantity, String currencyID){
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.currencyID = currencyID;
    }

    ............
}
```

I use a List to store several Objects. How can I sum up the total amount from every object store into the List?

Comment: Implementations of `List`, in Java, has a [`size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()) method; just invoke it and it will give you the number of elements inside it. If you want the accumulation sum of the `amount` member (for all of the elements), you need to traverse the collection, convert the value to the appropriate type and compute that (or do something more funny with Streams and things like that if you use Java 8).

Comment: By amount, do you mean the string property "amount"?

Comment: why amount is String in first place?

Comment: Yes, I need amount. I use PayPal SDK. It's a String filed.

Comment: so parse it and make a loop to whole list and use new variable as total amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of Java 8 Stream API and implement something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PaymentDetailsItem payment = new PaymentDetailsItem("test", "100.00", 10, "1");
    PaymentDetailsItem payment2 = new PaymentDetailsItem("test number 2", "250.00", 10, "2");

    List<PaymentDetailsItem> payments = new ArrayList<>();
    payments.add(payment);
    payments.add(payment2);

    List<String> amounts = payments.stream().map(PaymentDetailsItem::getAmount).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("Here we have the extracted List of amounts: " + amounts);

    String totalAmount = amounts.stream()
            .reduce((amount1, amount2) -> String.valueOf(Float.valueOf(amount1) + Float.valueOf(amount2))).get();
    System.out.println("Total amount obtained by using .reduce() upon the List of amounts: " + totalAmount);

    System.out.println("Or you can do everything at once: " + payments.stream().map(PaymentDetailsItem::getAmount)
            .reduce((amount1, amount2) -> String.valueOf(Float.valueOf(amount1) + Float.valueOf(amount2))).get());
}
```

Remember to implement the getter for the amount attribute.

Comment: Thanks you very much!